# How do you uncheck a checkbox in AutoIt?

Tags: checkbox, autoit

How do I uncheck a checkbox?

I really want this checkbox 'un-checked'. I was using send_keys before, and I could send it a toggle (space) "checked/unchecked", but it could actually be unchecked when I send the toggle and then it would be checked, which I don't want. I want it to be definitely UN-checked.

How do I do this?

Here's my AutoIt script so far:

```
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $Title = "Campus Portal Install"

Run("C:\Temp\PortalInstall-13_1_A_HF5_0003\cmcportalinstall.exe")

WinWaitActive($Title)

Send("z:\CampusPortal\")

ControlCommand($Title, "", "cbBackupIIS", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand($Title, "", "[NAME:cbBackupIIS]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand($Title, "", 1049322, "UnCheck")
ControlCommand($Title, "", "[CLASS:#1049322]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand($Title, "", "CLASS:Button]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand($Title, "", "[WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.2004eee]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand("Campus Portal Install", "", "cbBackupIIS", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand("Campus Portal Install", "", "[NAME:cbBackupIIS]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand("Campus Portal Install", "", 1049322, "UnCheck")
ControlCommand("Campus Portal Install", "", "[CLASS:#1049322]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand("Campus Portal Install", "", "CLASS:Button]", "UnCheck")
ControlCommand("Campus Portal Install", "", "[WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.2004eee]", "UnCheck")

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Title", "This message box will timeout after 10 seconds or select the OK button.", 10)
```

I've left in every variant I have tried; they don't error out so no harm in leaving them there; plus it shows what I've tried.

The ControlSend works fine.

Here's the control information:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Campus Portal Install
Class:  WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2004eee
Position:   496, 166
Size:   608, 523
Style:  0x16CF0000
ExStyle:    0x00050100
Handle: 0x00450334

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.2004eee
Instance:   15
ClassnameNN:    WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.2004eee15
Name:   cbBackupIIS
Advanced (Class):   [NAME:cbBackupIIS]
ID: 1049322
Text:   Backup IIS Entries?
Position:   108, 142
Size:   123, 15
ControlClick Coords:    55, 6
Style:  0x5601000B
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x001002EA

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   663, 337
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0xD6D3CE

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<
Version 13.1.a.hf5.0003\campusportal
Backup IIS Entries?
Backup Files?
...
C:\CampusPortalBackup\
Backup Path:
...
z:\CampusPortal\
Base Path:
E&xit
&Next >
Choose a base location and which applications will be installed.
Application Settings


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
App Pool Credentials
Password:
Username:
Use Integrated Authentication?
Configure Portal Database?
Run Portal SQL Update Scripts?
Portal
Password:
Username:
Database Name:
Server Name:
Campus
Password:
Username:
Database Name:
Server Name:
Host Header:
Register ASP.Net with IIS?
IP Address:
global
DSBXDANSQL01
Description:
Branding Folder:
URL Name:
You are now ready to install/remove the selected applications.  Click the Begin button below to start the installation/removal/configuration process.
Clear All
Select All
Campus List:
Student:
Applicant:
Activate?
Employer:
Staff:
...
http://localhost:80/
Portal:
http://localhost:99/
Configuration Tool:
http://localhost:98/
Admin Console:
127.0.0.1
SMTP Server:
seconds.
30
Query Interval:
50
Records Quantity:
Password:
NT Domain\User:
minute(s)
Staff Active Directory Settings:
dev
NT Domain:
dev.campusmgmt.com
Fully Qual.  Domain:
LDAP://OU=CampusUsers,DC=dev,DC=campusmgmt,DC=com
AD Path:
Student Active Directory Settings:
dev
NT Domain:
dev.campusmgmt.com
Fully Qual.  Domain:
LDAP://OU=CampusUsers,DC=dev,DC=campusmgmt,DC=com
AD Path:
1
Cache Refresh:
doc|rtf|pdf|xls|txt
0
Allowable File Types:
Cache Refresh Time:
Add
Allow IPs
...
http://localhost:91/
http://localhost:97/
Security Service:
Login Service:
...
http://localhost:95/
http://localhost:93/
http://localhost:92/
http://localhost:96/
Online Registration:
Payment Service:
Messaging Service:
http://localhost:94/
Reporting Service:
Portal Data Service:
\\DSBXDANSQL01\Reports
Default Report Path:
\\DSBXDANSQL01\Reports
Custom Report Path:
```

Comment: This command works: ControlSend($Title, "", "[NAME:cbBackupIIS]", " ") so at least I now know the correct way to address the control.

Comment: And I also tried using "UnCheck",""

Comment: IsChecked always returns 0. But IsEnabled does return 1.

Comment: A Button is no CheckBox... do you probably try to automate something you don't really want to? A quick and dirty hack would be to get the pixel color of it's center pixel and compare it to the value of a checked state.. then you only need to send space when it is checked... When you create your own GUI, you can use `GUICtrlRead($checkBox) == $GUI_CHECKED`... but this won't work for your existing GUI, right?

Comment: I'm trying to automate a vendor's installation gui. Weird that it's a button class, it looks like a checkbox. I tried a ControlClick on the window but that didn't toggle the checked state.

Comment: If the buttons position can't change, it might be the best workaround to check some pixel colors... they will be the same when the box is checked...

Comment: I can confirm this problem. "UnCheck" doesn't (apparently) do anything. Moreover, ControlCommand() seems to be generally broken: "Check" does not unconditionally check a checkbox - it toggles! For Combox'es: "FindString", "GetCurrentSelection" and "SelectString" do not seem to work as expected (instead of "SelectString" I was able to use the separate function _GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString() from <GuiComboBox.au3>). Updating to the latest official release of AutoIt, 2014-06-01, 3.3.12, does not make any difference. "IsEnabled" does work as expected, though (at least for buttons and checkboxes).

Comment: "IsChecked" does not work either. It always return 0, regardless of the state of the checkbox. "IsEnabled" is still the only one I have found to be working as expected.

Comment: What version of AutoIt are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From the example [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlCreateCheckbox.htm), you should be able to use `_IsChecked($hWnd)` to determine if a checkbox is checked. Button is the correct Class type of a checkbox.

Comment: I think the problem I'm having with Autoit, is that the functions to check control state only work with Autoit generated controls. But trying to access the control state of the Campus Portal Install application doesn't work because they are using a non-standard ... something. GUICtrlRead($hwnd) always returns 0.

Comment: I'm sure I have the right window. ControlGetHandle($Title, "", "[NAME:cbBackupIIS]") returns the same value as Autoit Window Info if I put the Finder Tool over the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Mine also always returned zero.

I managed to get it working using

```
   If ControlCommand("Login", "Login", $checkBox, "IsChecked") Then
       ControlCommand("Login", "Login", $checkBox, "Uncheck")
   EndIf
```